# MySQL Data Modeling on netbook

Tags: 10.04, mysql

Looking for a MySQL data modeling toll, that will actually fit on my netbook screen.

The official Workbench needs a higher resolution, so the bottom bit is cut off. Really annoying.

Is there an alternative out there? Or some 'trick' to make the workbench fit on my screen?

Comment: maybe and IDE with and plug-in can help you like eclipse or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "modeling tool" you mean something similar to MySQL Workbench in respects of defining tables and columns with all kinds of MySQL properties, generating CREATE and ALTER scripts from the definitions or setting foreign key relations in table diagrams, automatically adding the needed columns and constraints, then ... no. At least for Linux there's no such thing as an alternative to the Workbench, if the above features are what you want.

If all you need is a diagram drawing tool I'd very much recommend [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html). Or give dia (mentioned in another answer, cannot link to it here because of reputation limitations) a shot if for some reason you dislike nice looking diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

dia is a very good program to make diagrams of all type.

```
sudo apt-get install dia
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) is an easy-to-use interface and a "working-horse" for web-developers using the popular MySQL-Database. It allows you to manage and browse your databases and tables from an intuitive Windows® interface.

$ ./jheidi &

[Mogwai Java Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mogwai/files/Mogwai%20ER-Designer%20NG/) is a Java Entity Relationship design & modeling (ERD) for Oracle,MSSQL,Postgres,MySQL & DB2,Database change&dictionary management, Swing Data Binding,Swing visual designer, Apache FOP Renderer for dot matrix printers,Sparx Enterprise Architect Reports + more

java -jar mogwai-erdesignerng-2.6.0-standard.jar

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Administrator and Query Browser provide gui tools and are the predecessor(s) to MySQL Workbench. I am reading that the Administrator & Query Browser are going to be dropped from support, yet remain available for download. I use Ubuntu's repository maintained version of MySQL CE, which is 5.1 and the Administrator & Query Browser are provided as it's MySQL 5.1. I don't know if it will remain available and even functional for 5.5 and beyond. I can live without the modeling part of the gui Workbench tool.